# Bootstrap Model ajax form loading the complete ActionResult again inside model-body after MVC post

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrapping

so my bootstrap model-form is loaded like this in razor :

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Home", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "frmRes" }))
{

    <div tabindex="-1" class="modal fade" id="reservationModal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="reservationModalLabel" style="display: none;">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body" id="frmRes">
                    @Html.Partial("_Reservation")
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

on submitting, the above form the complete "Home\Index" view is loaded into the bootstrap model-form > model-content again instead of doing the actual view action;

This is the HomeController Code :

```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
      return View();  // <-this is loaded back into the model form
   } 

   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   [HandleError]
   public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include =ID,Naam,Van,Epos,Foon,Status,Tyd,Mense,Stamp,Datum,Neemkennis,Rook")] Bespreeking tafel)
   {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         db.Bespreekings.Add(tafel);
         db.SaveChanges();
         TempData["Message"] = "Success!";

         return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); //<-the above action
      }

      return PartialView("_Reservation", tafel);

   }
```

in other words whatever I return from the above "Create" action is returned back to the **model-content** **div** here is another example:

say I return :

```
return Content("Home\\Index") //just as an example
```

this would be the result

```
<div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-body" id="frmRes">Home\Index</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas what Am I missing - this is one of those things that used to work, and now not
(did not change any routing ...)

this is the complete html for form rendered :

```
<form action="/Home/Create" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#frmRes" id="form0" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">                            
<div tabindex="-1" class="modal fade show" id="reservationModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="reservationModalLabel" style="display: block; padding-right: 17px;">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body" id="frmRes">Home\Index</div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Here's something to check that may sound odd, but it is easy-to-check: make sure that all of the expected Javascript libraries are getting loaded *AND* also make sure that none of them are getting loaded _more than once_.

Comment: Try adding `InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace` to the existing `AjaxOptions`.